# RxJava: chaining results from map methods

Tags: java, rx-java

I am using RxJava for some time and have gotten stuck on the following pattern that repeats itself:

```
source
 .map(a -> b)
 .map(b -> c)
 .map(d -> func(a,b,c))
```

As you can see I need in a lower point of the chain some of results from the previous mapping methods.
I am not sure if this is a java limitation since lambda's cannot reference external parameters that are not final, or this is a build in limitation to Rx-Extensions.
My current solution is to use a wrapper that that holds a,b,c - and to add each one within the map, and then return the wrapper class. But this solution does not feel write.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

If the `map`s follow each other directly, you can compact them into a single map and have all intermediate data available to the final function:

```
source.map(a -> {
    T b = fa(a);
    U c = fc(b);
    return func(a, b, c);
})
```

Where `T` and `U` are the types of the intermediate values of `b` and `c` respectively.

Comment: that would be ok in the case of multiple maps. but once you have a filter or zip or any other combination it will not work

Comment: Then you have to use a wrapper at each stage.